# Tailwindcss Grid of Items with Dynamic Height

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I want to create a grid of photos as such:

[image: grid of photos]

where each cell may have different row height in order to maintain the picture's aspect ratio given a set width.

When I try to create a dummy prototype using `flex`, even if cells consume only as much height as they need (due to `h-min`), the cell under them is not placed directly under but there's a gap if one of the other items on the row is taller (see example below).

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="flex w-full flex-wrap">
  <div class="w-1/3 bg-red-100 h-min">item 1</div>
  <div class="w-1/3 bg-blue-100 h-min">item 2<br>extra tall</div>
  <div class="w-1/3 bg-yellow-100 h-min">item 3</div>
  <div class="w-1/3 bg-purple-100 h-min">item 4</div>
  <div class="w-1/3 bg-green-100 h-min">item 5</div>
  <div class="w-1/3 bg-fuchsia-100 h-min">item 6</div>
</div>
```

I was thinking about using three nested flexboxes within a parent flexbox, and while I don't see why that wouldn't work, I need to incorporate responsive design and change the number of columns to 1 on smaller screens, and using three separate flexboxes, one for each column would cause wrong display order.

Is there any way I can achieve what I need?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://tailwind-elements.com/docs/standard/components/gallery/).

Comment: I can't use that because they're using the approach I mentioned above I want to avoid due to responsiveness limitations. They're creating two child flexboxes within a parent flexbox, and on top of that, they're manually configuring the layout so that the two images under the wolf take up only half the size of the wolf image each. I can't do that because I won't know the images in the gallery at the time of coding (they'll be dynamically uploaded by users)

Comment: Then maybe [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_grid_responsive.asp) will help. It is done with plain css and html but does not manually configure the height.

Comment: That's the approach I mentioning above. Splitting the gird into three separate flexboxes. It works but it's messy because when I populate the content, I need to put every third item in first column, every third + 1 item in second column and every thid + 2 item in third column if I want to retain the original order

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`columns-{count}` utility](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/columns#adding-based-on-column-count) to control the column count and have dynamic column width, or the [`columns-{width}` utility](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/columns#adding-based-on-column-width) to control the column width and have dynamic column count. This won't work if you're going to have photos span horizontally across columns, though.

The gap between columns can be set with the [`gap-{size}` utility](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/gap), and the vertical space gap within a column can be set with the [`space-y-{amount}` utility](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/space).

```html
<!-- column-{width} difference seen at 1024px screeen width -->
<!-- <div class="columns-3xs md:columns-xs lg:columns-md gap-4 space-y-4 p-8"> -->
<!-- column-{count} -->
<div class="columns-1 md:columns-2 lg:columns-3 gap-4 space-y-4 p-8">
  <div class="h-min w-full bg-red-400">
    <img class="object-cover" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/700x400/?subway" alt="subway" />
  </div>
  <div class="h-min w-full bg-blue-400">
    <img class="object-cover" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/?city" alt="city" />
  </div>
  <div class="h-min w-full bg-orange-400">
    <img class="object-cover" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/700x300/?fruit" alt="fruit" />
  </div>
  <div class="h-min w-full bg-green-400">
    <img class="object-cover" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/700x500/?forest" alt="forest" />
  </div>
  <div class="h-min w-full bg-yellow-400">
    <img class="object-cover" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/?sunset" alt="sunset" />
  </div>
  <div class="h-min w-full bg-lime-400">
    <img class="object-cover" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/?desert" alt="desert" />
  </div>
  <div class="h-min w-full bg-fuchsia-400">
    <img class="object-cover" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/700x250/?ocean" alt="ocean" />
  </div>
  <div class="h-min w-full bg-teal-400">
    <img class="object-cover" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/700x300/?clouds" alt="clouds" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [Tailwind Play demo](https://play.tailwindcss.com/D46qDJ4mxn).